# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'cassandra.so' Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, cassandra, ubuntu-18.04

I have install php-cassandra from apt-get in Ubuntu 18.04.

```
sudo apt-get install php-cassandra 

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php-cassandra
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,892 B of archives.
After this operation, 21.5 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 php-cassandra amd64 1.3.0-1build1 [3,892 B]
Fetched 3,892 B in 0s (11.0 kB/s)        
Selecting previously unselected package php-cassandra.
(Reading database ... 256791 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../php-cassandra_1.3.0-1build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php-cassandra (1.3.0-1build1) ...
Setting up php-cassandra (1.3.0-1build1) ...
```

=================================================

```
php test_cass.php 

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'cassandra.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/cassandra.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/cassandra.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/cassandra.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/cassandra.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Cassandra' not found in /home/prabhakarc/php_programs/test_cass.php:3
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/prabhakarc/php_programs/test_cass.php on line 3
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Contents of test_cass.php:

```
<?php
  $cluster = new Cassandra::cluster()->withContactPoints('127.0.0.1')->build();
  $session = $cluster->connect("<Keyspace>");
  $statement = new Cassandra\SimpleStatement("SELECT * FROM <table>"); 
  $result = $session->execute($statement);
  echo "Result contains " . $result->count() . " rows"; ?> –
```

Comment: Can you edit your post with the first 5 lines of test_cass.php?  It sounds like you're not properly referencing the Cassandra library.

Comment: `<?php
$cluster   = Cassandra::cluster()->withContactPoints('127.0.0.1')->build();
$session   = $cluster->connect("<Keyspace>");
$statement = new Cassandra\SimpleStatement("SELECT * FROM <table>");
$result    = $session->execute($statement);
echo "Result contains " . $result->count() . " rows";
?>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Go to your php.ini file, look for `cassandra.so` and comment it out. Your .ini file should be in `/etc/php/your-php-version/cli/php.ini` and `/etc/php/your-php-version/apache/php.ini`. Comment out the said line by adding semi-colon before it like so `;extension=cassandra.so`. Then restart apache by doing so `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Cassandra' not found in /home/prabhakarc/php_programs/test_cass.php:3
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/prabhakarc/php_programs/test_cass.php on line 3. once i commented the line in /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-cassandra.ini then warning went off.

Comment: Where is your `libcassandra.so`... `/usr/local/lib` or `/usr/lib`...?

Comment: [ cassandra.so or libcassandra.so ] No one file is available in /usr/local/lib or /usr/lib.